# How to change the order of website items on a phone screen

Tags: html, css

On my website I have the following section:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center mb-4 mt-2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="w-100 col-md-12 pb-4 pt-1 bg-light">
        <div class="row align-items-center">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold">Step 1:</h4>
            <h5 class="pl-5 pr-5">Search for people based on your keywords.</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 mb-5 mt-4">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <img src="static/images/step1.jpg" class="img-fluid                                    
                                                        mx-auto d-block border" />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 mt-5 mb-5">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <img src="static/images/step2.jpg" class="img-fluid                                    
                                                        mx-auto d-block border" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold">Step 2:</h4>
            <h5 class="pl-5 pr-5">The results are sorted by a person's responsiveness. Choose from a\
 list of matches who are ready and willing to interact.</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <h4 class="font-weight-bold">Step 3:</h4>
            <h5 class="pl-5 pr-5">Message and make connections with people who are open for (real or\
 virtual) coffee!</h5>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-8 mt-5">
            <div class="icon-box">
              <img src="static/images/step3.jpg" class="img-fluid                                    
                                                        mx-auto d-block border" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which looks like:

[image]

But on a phone screen, the text (Step 1 etc.) and images are stacked on top of each other. But because of the layout it does not alternate text-image-text-image-text-image as I would like it to:

[image]

How to I change the order on a phone screen but keep the desktop layout the way it is please?

My CSS is here also:

```
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

body {
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
}

.lh-condensed {
  line-height: 1.25;
}

.main-header {
  max-width: 700px;
}

.ofc-main-title {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.ofc-title {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 24px;
}

a.ofc-link-title {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.ofc-link-title:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

a.ofc-link-title:active {
  color: #000000;
}

a.ofc-link-title:visited {
  color: #000000;
}
.ofc-main-subtitle {
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.ofc-footer {
  font-family: "Economica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

form#main-search-form {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

span#main-beta-tag {
  color: #FF1493;
  font-size: 16px;
}

span#beta-tag {
  color: #FF1493;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#onboarding-title {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.onboarding-panel {
  background-color: #FBF7F0;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.onboarding-img {
  width: 250px;
}
.onboarding-text {
  font-weight: 900;
}

.step-panel {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.step-text {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.step-img {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

span#looking-for {
  color: #1C99CE;
}

@media(max-width:767px) {
  .step-text {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .step-img {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .step-img {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  .step-img img {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  .step-text {
    background: none;
  }

  .steps {
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #d9d6d6;
  }

  .onboarding-panel .steps:first-child .step-text {
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  }

  .step-img {
    background: none !important;
  }

  .ofc-main-title {
    font-size: 35px;
  }

  #search-form {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }

  .border-bottom {
    display: block !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }

  #search-form .btn {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px
  }
}

.icon-box {
    margin: 0px 20px;
}

.icon-box p {
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

Comment: on mobile screen, you can change the order of the flex items. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added to your media query for `@media (max-width: 767px) {}` the `order` property of `flex-box` in a way the desired output is achieved.

```css
html {
  font-size: 14px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  html {
    font-size: 16px;
  }
}

body {
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 960px;
}

.lh-condensed {
  line-height: 1.25;
}

.main-header {
  max-width: 700px;
}

.ofc-main-title {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 40px;
}

.ofc-title {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 24px;
}

a.ofc-link-title {
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a.ofc-link-title:hover {
  color: #000000;
}

a.ofc-link-title:active {
  color: #000000;
}

a.ofc-link-title:visited {
  color: #000000;
}
.ofc-main-subtitle {
  font-family: "PT Sans", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 24px;
}

.ofc-footer {
  font-family: "Economica", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
}

form#main-search-form {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

span#main-beta-tag {
  color: #ff1493;
  font-size: 16px;
}

span#beta-tag {
  color: #ff1493;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#onboarding-title {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.onboarding-panel {
  background-color: #fbf7f0;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.onboarding-img {
  width: 250px;
}
.onboarding-text {
  font-weight: 900;
}

.step-panel {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.step-text {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: left;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.step-img {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 49%;
  text-align: right;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 20px;
}

span#looking-for {
  color: #1c99ce;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .one {
    order: 1;
  }

  .two {
    order: 2;
  }

  .three {
    order: 4;
  }

  .four {
    order: 3;
  }

  .five {
    order: 5;
  }

  .six {
    order: 6;
  }
  .step-text {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .step-img {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .step-img {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding: 0px;
  }

  .step-img img {
    width: 100% !important;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
  }

  .step-text {
    background: none;
  }

  .steps {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 1px 1px #d9d6d6;
  }

  .onboarding-panel .steps:first-child .step-text {
    padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  }

  .step-img {
    background: none !important;
  }

  .ofc-main-title {
    font-size: 35px;
  }

  #search-form {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }

  .border-bottom {
    display: block !important;
    text-align: center !important;
  }

  #search-form .btn {
    margin-top: 10px !important;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
}

.icon-box {
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.icon-box p {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>JS Bin</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center mb-4 mt-2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="w-100 col-md-12 pb-4 pt-1 bg-light">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
              <div class="col-md-4 one">
                <h4 class="font-weight-bold">Step 1:</h4>
                <h5 class="pl-5 pr-5">
                  Search for people based on your keywords.
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8 mb-5 mt-4 two">
                <div class="icon-box">
                  <img
                    src="static/images/step1.jpg"
                    class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block border"
                    alt="image-1"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8 mt-5 mb-5 three">
                <div class="icon-box">
                  <img
                    src="static/images/step2.jpg"
                    class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block border"
                    alt="image-2"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-4 four">
                <h4 class="font-weight-bold">Step 2:</h4>
                <h5 class="pl-5 pr-5">
                  The results are sorted by a person's responsiveness. Choose
                  from a\ list of matches who are ready and willing to interact.
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4 five">
                <h4 class="font-weight-bold">Step 3:</h4>
                <h5 class="pl-5 pr-5">
                  Message and make connections with people who are open for
                  (real or\ virtual) coffee!
                </h5>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-8 mt-5 six">
                <div class="icon-box">
                  <img
                    src="static/images/step3.jpg"
                    class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block border"
                    alt="image-3"
                  />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

That's the beauty of `order` property in flexbox. It is very very helpful in these scenarios.

Comment: @user1551817: Hope this helps. I did it on my own laptop first and only when it worked correctly updated here.  Do rate and accept dear, if this has helped you :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If i undrestand your question correctly you want to display text image , text image , text image from top to down in mobile screen?

first add a container for each row, something like this

```
    <div class="row text-center mb-4 mt-2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="w-100 col-md-12 pb-4 pt-1 bg-light">
                <div class="row align-items-center">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h4 class="font-weight-bold">Step 1:</h4>
                            <h5 class="pl-5 pr-5">Search for people based on your keywords.</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-8 mb-5 mt-4">
                            <div class="icon-box">
                                <img src="image1" class="img-fluid                                    
                                                        mx-auto d-block border" />
            </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-8 mt-5 mb-5">
                                <div class="icon-box">
                                    <img src="image2" class="img-fluid                                    
                                                        mx-auto d-block border" />
            </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <h4 class="font-weight-bold">Step 2:</h4>
                                    <h5 class="pl-5 pr-5">The results are sorted by a person's responsiveness. Choose
                                        from
                                        a\
                                        list of matches who are ready and willing to interact.</h5>
                                </div>



                            </div>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                    <h4 class="font-weight-bold">Step 3:</h4>
                                    <h5 class="pl-5 pr-5">Message and make connections with people who are open for
                                        (real
                                        or\
                                        virtual) coffee!</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-8 mt-5">
                                    <div class="icon-box">
                                        <img src="image3" class="img-fluid                                    
                                                        mx-auto d-block border" />
            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Then in when you are inside mobile mode add a class to the second container with this properties

```
.yourClass {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column-reverse;
}
```